# How to convert timestamp to hour/minutes/seconds in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I am calculating how much time my code is taking in shell script -

```
date1=$(date +"%s")

# some code here

date2=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "Time Taken - $(($diff / 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

Above script prints out time taken in minutes and seconds. How can I add it for hours as well?  Meaning it should print out `Time Taken - 0 hours 54 minutes 0 seconds` something like this.

Comment: What about `echo "Time Taken - $(($diff / 3600)) hours $(($diff / 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."`

Comment: Minutes calculation is wrong.. It should be `$(((diff/60) % 60))`...

Comment: @anishsane are you sure it is wrong? I thought it was right?

Comment: Consider diff=3723 seconds. (1hr, 2 mins, 3 seconds). Existing code will give `Time Taken - 1 hours 62 minutes and 3 seconds elapsed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "Time Taken - $((diff /60/60)) hours and $(($diff % 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What does this mean? `/60/60`?

Comment: That means divide by 60 (minutes) devide by 60 (hours. It is the same as diveide by 3600 if you will converte seconds to hours.

Comment: Minutes calculation is wrong.. It should be `$(((diff/60) % 60))`

Answer (score 0):

if you're starting with integer seconds that all fall within a single day, and only need `HH:MM:SS`, here's a very strange way to use `jot + bc` :

> ```
>  jot -w 'obase = 60; ' - 91 86400 9091 | bc
> ```

```
 01 31
 02 33 02
 05 04 33
 07 36 04
 10 07 35
 12 39 06
 15 10 37
 17 42 08
 20 13 39
 22 45 10
```